# resizing dockpanel after animation, VB

Tags: wpf

I resize a dock panel like this:

```
Private WithEvents PanelAnimation As New DoubleAnimation
Private WithEvents PanelSB As New Storyboard

With PanelAnimation
        .From = WpfDockPanel.ActualHeight
        .To = s
        .Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
        .AccelerationRatio = 0.5
        .DecelerationRatio = 0.5
End With
PanelSB.Children.Add(PanelAnimation)
Storyboard.SetTarget(PanelAnimation, WpfDockPanel)
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(PanelAnimation, New PropertyPath(DockPanel.HeightProperty))
PanelSB.Begin(AviMainWindow)
```

..which works fine. Then, I want to manually set the size, but it won't change, if I stop the code and type in a different size, the size won't change, it is as though it is readonly.

But if I change the size once, not by animating, just by setting the size, I can change it again no problem. Why can't I manually set the height after animating?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the animation's [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) is set to `HoldEnd` by default. You could set it to `Stop`.

You would however also have to set the `Height` property of the animation target to the desired end value manually before starting the animation. Otherwise it would flip back to the value it had before the animation was started.

```
With PanelAnimation
        .FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
        ...

...
WpfDockPanel.Height = s
PanelSB.Begin(AviMainWindow)
```

Comment: PERFECT! Easy when you know how.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to remove the value applied by the animation. Something like

```
WpfDockPanel.BeginAnimation(DockPanel.HeightProperty, null)
```

should do the trick.